# Three Display UI in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create an app in WPF, in which once the user will launch it. App will have three screen on three different monitor. 
Once i launch it, i can see one page.Can you please suggest how to achieve above scenario.

Comment: try explaining what you have already tried, and what doesnt work

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed for it. Any references would be helpful. If some one knows about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question on [social.microsoft.com](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/5d181304-8952-4663-8c3c-dc4d986aa8dd) describes a two form on two monitor solution.